# Clearing an animated plot in tkinter to reload animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, arduino

I have an arduino connected to a pressure sensor collecting data. I am able to connect to the sensor and plot the data with an animation via the code below in a tkinter window/frame. When I open the tkinter window, I click the graph button and the animation loads as expected. I want to click the clear button to delete the animation and then click graph again get new data. Ive played around with plt clear, forgetting the pack and other options but still have not found a solution.

Any help would be appreciated...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import serial
import datetime

root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (width, height))
root.configure(background='white')
root.title("CMJ")

global data, times
times = []
data = []

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(0, 40)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

def animate(i):
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-1420', 115200, timeout=1)
    for i in range(20):
        raw = ser.readline()
        dec = raw.decode()
        strline = dec.split(" ")
        lines = float(strline[0])
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now1 = now.strftime('%M:%S.%f')
        now = now1[:-5]
        data.append(lines)
        times.append(now)
        ser.close()
        line, = ax.plot(times, data, label="Force", color="blue")
        line.set_ydata(data)
        x = max(data)
        most.configure(text=x)
        return line,

def graph():
    graphframe.pack(pady=20)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graphframe)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=19, repeat=FALSE, interval=20, cache_frame_data=FALSE)
    canvas.draw()


def clear():
    plt.close("all")

buttonframe = Frame(root)
buttonframe.pack()
graphframe = Frame(root)
graphframe.pack()
button = tk.Button(buttonframe, text='graph', command=graph, width=15)
button.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text='clear', command=clear, width=15)
button2.pack()
most = tk.Label(buttonframe, text="0")
most.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Ive tried to forget the frame, but when I repack, the frame pops up with he old completed animation and not with new values. In the animate function, when I print the data and times, it actually saves new values into he variables but I cannot get them to reanimate the plot with the new data.

Comment: This line `return line,` breaks the loop on the first iteration. The return statement must be at the same level as the loop.

Comment: Are you resetting your global variables somewhere in the code?

Comment: @8349697 - The animation works fine as is, im just looking to re animate with new values. If I move the return line, to the same level the animation does not load properly unfortunately.

Ive changed the code to clear the global variables in the clear function, when I do this, I can print the variables and it is collecting new data and storing them appropriately but the animation still stays as the first set of data.

Comment: Ive looked into the animation.FuncAnimation and I think there is a solution looking me in the face but I dont know how best to implement it. In the link below it mentions two things: init_func and new_frame_seq(),

Ive not been able to correctly implement these two as I am not too familiar with them. Ive tried to recall the animate function but it wont let me call it as it says I need an argument, the (i) I think, when I call the function animate(i) it also gives me an error.

Thank you for your responses!

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it took me 3 days and A LOT of searching, trial and error but ive been able to get the desired result. It may not be the most efficient but it's a start.

Ive created a new function to create the subplots `setup()` I call that initially when the program opens. Then in the `clear()` function I am able to forget the canvas widget, reset the variables and call the `setup()` function again. Now when I click `graph()` function it creates a new graph.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import serial
import datetime

root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (width, height))
root.configure(background='white')
root.title("CMJ")

times = []
data = []


def setup():
    global fig, ax
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_ylim(0, 40)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

def animate(i):
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-1420', 115200, timeout=1)
    for i in range(20):
        raw = ser.readline()
        dec = raw.decode()
        strline = dec.split(" ")
        lines = float(strline[0])
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        now1 = now.strftime('%M:%S.%f')
        now = now1[:-5]
        data.append(lines)
        times.append(now)
        ser.close()
        line, = ax.plot(times, data, label="Force", color="blue")
        line.set_ydata(data)
        x = max(data)
        most.configure(text=x)
        print(times, data)
        return line,
    graph()

def graph():
    global canvas
    graphframe.pack(pady=20)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graphframe)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=19, repeat=FALSE, interval=20, cache_frame_data=TRUE)
    canvas.draw()

def clear():
    global times, data
    times = []
    data = []
    canvas.get_tk_widget().forget()
    setup()


buttonframe = Frame(root)
buttonframe.pack()
graphframe = Frame(root)
graphframe.pack()
button = tk.Button(buttonframe, text='graph', command=graph, width=15)
button.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text='clear', command=clear, width=15)
button2.pack()
most = tk.Label(buttonframe, text="0")
most.pack()

setup()

root.mainloop()
```

If you notice any thing I am overlooking, anything that is unnecessary or overkill please let me know.

Thank you for your time, hope this helps if you arr encountering something similar.